# Quit the Looper of a Thread

Tags: android, multithreading, android-looper

This is a more general question about how to handle the Threads and Loopers in Android, thus the code is a bit generalized.

Consider the following class `DoSomethingClass`, which has to start some kind of action that needs listening for events (like cellular rssi changes, location changes etc).

```
public class DoSomethingClass {
    private Thread listenForSomethingThread;

    private void startDoingSomething() {
        listenForSomethingThread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                Looper.prepare();
                SomethingListener listener = new SomethingListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSomethingHappened(Something something) {
                        // Quit looper if interrupted
                        if (Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()) {
                            Looper.myLooper().quit();
                        } else {
                            // Do stuff with the Something if not                           
                        }
                    }
                }

                SomethingManager somMan = // Retrieve it
                somMan.requestSomethingUpdates(listener);
                Looper.loop();  // Blocks until Looper is quitted
                somMan.removeSomethingUpdates(listener);                
            }
        });
        listenForSomethingThread.start();
    }

    private void stopDoingSomething() {
        listenForSomethingThread.interrupt();
    }
}
```

Pretty simple: When I call `startDoingSomething()`, a new Thread gets spawned that creates a listener listening for events and handling them (eg. logging, automated yelling at callers etc). For this, it prepares and starts a looper.

When I am finished, I call `stopDoingSomething()`, which interrupts the Thread: At the next event, nothing will be done, but the Thread will clean up and terminate.

And here's the problem: What if that event *never* occurs? Then the check for interruption will never be called, the looper will never be quit and will loop forever!?

Is there any way to get a Thread's Looper from another thread, in order to quit it? Or is there a possibility to let it listen for timing intervals in addition to its normal listenees?

Comment: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Looper :here in example you will see that you can interact with looper by sending messages. Now if you want to quit send that message. Many example will surface if you will google android looper with message example

Comment: i'd advise you to use a `HandlerThread` and implement a `Handler` associated to it. You can pass messages to the handler, and you may define a special one for quitting the thread

Comment: @nandsito: Just using a `HandlerThread` instead of the `Thread` would be perfect for me as `HandlerThread` has a `quit()` method. Unfortunately, calling it from another thread blocks the app ad infinitum. How could a `Handler` be implemented in my example?

Answer (score 0):

I slightly changed your code sample. You can quit the looper like this:

```java
public class DoSomethingClass {
    private Thread listenForSomethingThread;
    private Looper looper; // create this field

    private void startDoingSomething() {
        listenForSomethingThread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                Looper.prepare();
                looper = Looper.myLooper(); // store the looper here
                SomethingListener listener = new SomethingListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSomethingHappened(Something something) {
                        // Quit looper if interrupted
                        if (Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()) {
                            Looper.myLooper().quit();
                        } else {
                            // Do stuff with the Something if not                           
                        }
                    }
                }

                SomethingManager somMan = // Retrieve it
                somMan.requestSomethingUpdates(listener);
                Looper.loop();  // Blocks until Looper is quitted
                somMan.removeSomethingUpdates(listener);                
            }
        });
        listenForSomethingThread.start();
    }

    private void stopDoingSomething() {
        looper.quit(); // quit the looper
        listenForSomethingThread.interrupt();
    }
}
```

**But** I guess this looper isn't doing anything because its message queue is not receiving any messages. The listener may be running in the UI thread, which is not what you want, I presume.

Comment: So you are basically laying a direct cable to the looper from the outside. Wouldn't it be slightly better to have the interrupt before the `looper.quit()` then?

Comment: @Bowi an interrupt is just a signal to a thread. And by interrupting a thread and quitting a looper you are mixing two Android thread APIs, which increases complexity and may cause confusion. Furthermore, as I stated in the answer, the looper thread isn't doing any work. I guess you need advice on the design before trying to program an Android looper